# Character input with %d causing infinite loop

Tags: c, loops, io, scanf

```
 int valid=0, running=1;
    printf("\n1. Generate\n2. Retrieve");
    while(!valid){
        printf("\n\nEnter choice> ");
        scanf("%d", &c);
        if(c==1){
            valid=1;
            generate();
            while(running){
                printf("\n\nPress Y to generate again. Press N to retrieve> ");
                scanf(" %c", retry);
                if(retry == 'Y' || retry == 'y'){
                    idx++;
                    generate();
                }else if(retry == 'N' || retry == 'n')
                    running = 0;
                else
                    printf("Invalid input. Try again.");
            }
            retrieve();
        }else if(choice==2){
            valid = 1;
            retrieve();
        }else
            printf("Invalid input. Try again");
    }
```

Here the user should enter either 1 or 2. If the user enters any other number or character then I want to ask the user to input again. The program works fine if the user enters any other number like 5/6/7 etc. But if the user enters a character the program goes into an infinite loop. I can break the loop with a scanf status check but then the program stops. Instead, I want to prompt the user to input again if he enters anything except 1 or 2.

Comment: Step 1: check the return value of `scanf("%d", &c);`.  Is it 1?

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: kerbx4, What should happen if the choice is an empty line?  Wait for more input OR prompt and then wait for new input?

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Very nice.  Filing that for future reference.

Comment: You seem to have `c` (in the `if`) and `choice` (in the `else if`) muddled up ... but you haven't shown the declarations of either. Please post code we can actually test.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apparently, using `scanf` with `%d`, but input characters causes buffer issues. See code below for one way to avoid the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void generate(){
    printf("generate\n");
}

void retrieve(){
    printf("retrieve\n");
}

int main(){
    int valid=0, running=1, idx=0, c=-100;
    char retry;
    char s[25];
    printf("\n1. Generate\n2. Retrieve");
    while(!valid){
        printf("\n\nEnter choice> ");
        scanf("%s", s);
        c = atoi(s);
        if(c==1){
            valid=1;
            generate();
            while(running){
                printf("\n\nPress Y to generate again. Press N to retrieve> ");
                while(scanf(" %c", &retry)==0);
                if(retry == 'Y' || retry == 'y'){
                    idx++;
                    generate();
                }else if(retry == 'N' || retry == 'n')
                    running = 0;
                else
                    printf("Invalid input. Try again.");
            }
            retrieve();
        }else if(c==2){
            valid = 1;
            retrieve();
        }else
            printf("Invalid input. Try again");
    }
    
    return(0);
}
```

One possible execution is shown below:

```
1. Generate
2. Retrieve

Enter choice> Bad
Invalid input. Try again

Enter choice> Worse
Invalid input. Try again

Enter choice> 1
generate


Press Y to generate again. Press N to retrieve> Y
generate


Press Y to generate again. Press N to retrieve> n
retrieve
```

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` returns the number of successful input assignments, or `EOF` on end of file or error.  You should get in the habit of checking this return value.  In this case of `scanf( "%d", &c )`, you should expect a return value of `1` on a successful input.

The `%d` conversion specifier tells `scanf` to skip over any leading whitespace, then read characters up to the first character that *isn't* a decimal digit, leaving that character in the input stream.

Example - suppose you enter `"12.3"` as an input.  `scanf( "%d", &c )` will read, convert, and assign the `"12"` portion of the input to `c` and return `1`.  The `".3"` portion of the input is left in the input stream.

If you call `scanf( "%d", &c )` again, the first thing it sees is that `'.'` character, so it immediately stops reading (you have a *matching failure*).

Since no input was actually read, nothing gets assigned to `c` and `scanf` returns `0`.  This will keep happening until you remove that `'.'` character with some other input operation like `getchar()` or `scanf( "%*c" )`, etc.

You should always check the result of `scanf` to make sure you read as many items as you expect:

```
int r = 0;
do
{
  r = scanf( "%d", &c );
  if ( r == EOF )
  {
    // end of file or error signaled on the input stream; in this case we
    // just exit the program
    exit( 0 );
  }
  else if ( r == 0 )
  {
    // matching failure - there's a bad character in the input stream
    // remove it with getchar and try again
    getchar();
  }
} while( r != 1 );

// at this point we either have good input or have already exited the program
```